# Listing Virtual Machines on my Azure account through the Java SDK

Tags: java, azure

I am developing an application that tries to fetch as much information out of Azure as possible. Is there any way using the Java SDK to get a list of the Virtual Machines I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to list Virtual Machines in your subscription, you would need to perform [`Service Management REST API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx) Operations. I briefly looked at Azure SDK for Java on [`Github`](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java) and I don't think the API is implemented there. I only saw support for Storage, Media Services and Service Bus. What that means is that you would need to write some code yourself which consumes this REST API.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of azure java sdk supports listing virtual machines. You need to import following packages

```
group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure', version: '1.12.0'
group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.3'
group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.0.0'
```

Then authenticate with client id and client secret

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials('<client id>', '<tenant id>', '<client secret>', AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription('SubscriptionGuid');
```

Then use the following code to list virtual machines

```
PagedList<VirtualMachine> vms = azure.virtualMachines().list();
```